# Fixed:Lanscape only not working in iOS5

Tags: xcode, ios5

I have updated my iPod to iOS5 and xcode to 4.2 but none of my application views are running in landscape i have done the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Although the default for this line is:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

In my view i have set orientation to Landscape.
In Summary under 'Supported Device Orientations' i only have Landscape left selected.
And lastly in Info.plist i have added Initial interface orientation = Landscape (left home button)

So when i run on my iPod & iPhone Simulator running iOS5 the device rotes left but the view does not move much.

But if i run it on iPhone Simulator running 4.2 it rotes and becomes landscape.

I don't know if this is something i am doing wrong with the new iOS/xcode or there is a problem.

Thanks in advance.
Eli

UPDATE PROBLEM SOLVED:
It was caused by

> Initial interface orientation = Landscape
>   (left home button)

Changed it to

> Initial interface orientation = Portrait (bottom home button)

Comment: You should write your solution in an answer, and then mark it correct.  
It makes it easier to check if there is an answer, and you get reputation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE PROBLEM SOLVED: It was caused by

Initial interface orientation = Landscape (left home button)

Changed it to

Initial interface orientation = Portrait (bottom home button)

Comment: This partially fixed the issue for me.  However, when my application starts and the iPad orientation is set to locked, the application starts in Portrait.  The user must unlock the iPad orientation for the application to display properly in Landscape.